# No plugin found in Xcode with Cordova 2.1.0

Tags: xcode, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I use the same code as I did in Cordova 2.0 Xcode project. But since I installed cordova 2.1.0 and updated new XCode I keep getting theese messages in console (not only for ChildBrwoser plugin, but for any plugin I try to use):

> ERROR: Plugin 'ChildBrowser' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. 
>   Check your plugin mapping in Cordova.plist.

In `Cordova.plist` everything is ok - "Plugins" part filled with proper values. XCode project was build successfully.

Why is it happening?

Comment: As it came to me the problem was in XCode caching the Cordova.plist file. The only way to drop the cache I found was changing provisioning certificates. Actually even Product>Clean never helped.

Comment: I have my developer certificate and one for Ad-Hoc distribution, so i just changed it in project settings and it helped me. Im pretty sure it's about caching Cordova.plist because when I renamed it to Cordova2.plist the app started well...

Answer (score 0):

iOS plugins for PhoneGap 2.0 seem to be incompatible with PhoneGap 2.1. See [this page in the docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_plugin-development_ios_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20iOS) under "Plugin Signatures".

I was facing this issue with the UrbanAirship PhoneGap-plugin. As my Objective-C skills are non-existent and I don't have the time to figure it out, I just downgraded to PhoneGap 2.0.

Comment: That is not true since old signature became only DEPRECATED and still can be used.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the exact same issue with Janrain Engage for iOS and i believe that these plugins are not compatible with Phonegap 2.1 but @DmitriyLezhnev is also making a good point here.

Answer (score 0):

If you update to phonegap 2.3.0 you can start using InAppBrowser which will be apart of the build.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the [screen-shot](https://raw.github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/master/iOS/ChildBrowser/Cordova.plist.png) which shows you how to insert a plugin in plist actually lies.
you should add the key `ChildBrowser` but not `ChildBrowserCommand`! This fixes the issue.